# how to apply aggregate in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Through the following query in MongoDb , I get all the teams from the entire data.

```
db.player_level_data.aggregate([{$group : {_id: {team_name : "$team_name"}}}]).toArray()
```

I need to import this array of teams in python through pymongo.I tried the following code.

```
pipe = [
{'$group': {'_id': {'team_name' : "$team_name"}}}
]
data  = db.player_level_data.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
pprint (data)
```

But it printed a pymongo cursor object. Any ideas on this. Thanks

Comment: Another update .. i tried printing `pprint(data.next()) which printed the first team name. This implies that after iterating over the cursor object, I might be able to get all the team names. Is there any way to to avoid cursor object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume cursor object is [generator](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html), so simply convert it to list and print that list:

```
pprint(list(data))
```

Note that data whould be empty after printing. so if you need to continue work on that data save `list(data)` to variable and interact with that variable:

```
l_data = list(data)
pprint(l_data)
```

Comment: Hey Andriy, an element of my list is as follows

   ` {u'_id': {u'team_code': 7, u'team_id': 2, u'team_name': u'Aston Villa'}}`
How do i get values for individuals keys.

Comment: element.get('id') or element['id']

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this returns a cursor object.

```
list(cursor)
```

should get you a list of the items.